# How to replace substring in column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
feed
==========
garden_1
garden_2
equipment
device
```

I need to replace `garden_*` with `total_*`.

How ca  I do it?

This is what I tried?

```
df["feed"] = np.where(("garden" in df.feed), "total", df.feed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dataframe.replace function and use regular expression to match strings.

Try this code:

`df = df['feed'].replace(to_replace ='garden_*', value = 'total_', regex = True)`.

**Reference:**
[pandas.DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` and `str.contains` to do this:

```
df['feed'] = np.where(df['feed'].str.contains(r'garden',case=False),'total',df['feed'])
```

which will get you what you need.